# How do I add X-Request-Start in HAProxy?

Tags: newrelic, haproxy

We'd like to track request queue times, and as per https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/other-features/request-queueing/configuring-request-queue-reporting, we need to add `X-Request-Start` or `X-Queue-Start` with the timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 12):

Using `%Ts` is **NOT** the correct solution as it is the start time of the session (stream) and not the request time. Multiple requests will use the same `%Ts` time. [See more details here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/23269)

The correct solution for haproxy version **<1.9** is to use the following in the `frontend` block. Unfortunately it only has seconds resolution.

```
http-request set-header X-Request-Start t=%[date()]
```

If you are using haproxy version **>=1.9** there is a new sample fetch method [date_us()](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/commit/a792a0aa9344605a94749dc431a43778432b2311#diff-e27e37b18fbdafa1f906eb12f7b89604) which can be used to get microseconds resolution.

```
http-request set-header X-Request-Start t=%[date()]%[date_us()]
```

Note: [The newrelic agents can automatically handle timestamps values sent using seconds, milliseconds, or as microseconds](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/features/configuring-request-queue-reporting).

Comment: the link  for 'See more details here' is not active. Google cache is also not present. Do you have any other link for the explanation?

Comment: From what I recall: %Ts timestamp is when the TCP connection is accepted, but HTTP (+ HTTP/2) requests can be pipelined or use keepalive. eg: Browser with a 10 second keepalive may only send a request after a few seconds, but the %Ts send to the backend will be the initial time of the connection was accepted, which is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add this line in your `frontend` block. You'll need one for HTTP and HTTPS.

`http-request set-header X-Request-Start t=%Ts%ms`

Comment: This is not the right solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50060498/2551154 for the details.